# Showing $N(T\circ T)=N(T)\Leftrightarrow R(T\circ T)=R(T)$ if $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $T:R^n\to R^n$ be a linear operator. Show that
>
> $$\text{Null space}(T\circ T)=\text{Null space}(T)\Leftrightarrow\text{Range}(T\circ T)=\text{Range}(T)$$

What I tried :
$T(v)=Av$ (Any linear transformation can be written in this form).
$T(T(v))=A(A(v))=A^2 v$

$N(T): Av=0$

$N(T\circ T(v)) :  A^2 v =0$

Now I don't know how to continue or if my approach was correct in this first place.

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed hint please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a basic use of rank nullity theorem.

If $\operatorname{Range}(T) = \operatorname{Range}(T^2)$, then
\begin{gather}
\operatorname{Rank}(T) + \operatorname{Nullity}(T) = n \\
\operatorname{Rank}(T^2) + \operatorname{Nullity}(T^2) = n
\end{gather}
and thus $\operatorname{Nullity}(T) = \operatorname{Nullity}(T^2)$.  Since $\operatorname{Null}(T) \subseteq \operatorname{Null}(T^2)$, we have that $\operatorname{Null}(T) = \operatorname{Null}(T^2)$

Similar argument if $\operatorname{Null}(T) = \operatorname{Null}(T^2)$, except we use that $\operatorname{Range}(T^2) \subseteq \operatorname{Range}(T)$

Comment: Why is Null(T) a subspace of Null(ToT)?

Comment: @HasanHammoud If $v\in\mathrm{Null}(T)$, then $T\circ T(v)=T(0)=0$, so $v\in\mathrm{Null}(T\circ T)$.